# rich:contextMenu on left click

Tags: richfaces, contextmenu

We are migrating our web app from JSF 1.2 to 2.2. We used to have a context menu activated on left click with the help of rich:componentControl.

Now, we would like to use rich:contextMenu attached to rich:extendedDataTable. Is it possible to make it work on left click instead of default right click?

Thanks ahead,
Anja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `showEvent="onclick"` on your `richContextMenu` to switch from the default `oncontextmenu` to a left-click.

Comment: The event names come without the `on`.